# Logged user based connection string in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity, multi-tenant, dbcontext, asp.net-core-1.1

I have an application that uses identity database to store users and customers.

Each customer has also a separate database with its data and its connection string is stored in `Customer` table in the identity database.

`AspNetUsers` has a field to tell which customer the user belongs to (also identity db).

I want to assign connection string to the user when he logs in and make it available in the application for the duration of the session.

I currently have customer model:

```
public partial class `Customer`
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int NoLicenses { get; set; }
    public bool? Enabled { get; set; }
    public string CustomerConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```

and user model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }

    public bool? IsEnabled { get; set; }

    // there ideally I'd have a connstring property
}
```

The models map db table fields.

I'm using .NET Core 1.1 and EF Core.

Answer (score 1):

With the defalut ASP.NET Identity template , you can :

1. extend the ApplicationUser class in `Models` folder :

   ```
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
   {
       public string CustomerId { get; set; }

       public bool? IsEnabled { get; set; }

       //add your custom claims
       public string CustomerConnectionString { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Add your custom model to `ApplicationDbContext` in Data folder :

   ```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
   {
       public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
           : base(options)
       {
       }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
       {
           base.OnModelCreating(builder);
           // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
           // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
           // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);


       }

       public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Sync your database : Add-Migration xxxx , then run the Update-Database command in Package Manager Console . Now you have the Customer table and have `CustomerConnectionString` column in `AspNetUsers` table.
4. Create you own implementation of IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory by inheriting the default one to generate a ClaimsPrincipal from your user :

   ```
   public class AppClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
   {
       public AppClaimsPrincipalFactory(
         UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
         , RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager
         , IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
       : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
       { }

       public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
       {
           var principal = await base.CreateAsync(user);

           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.CustomerId))
           {

               ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(new[] {
               new Claim("customid", user.CustomerId)
               });
           }

           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.CustomerConnectionString))
           {

               ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(new[] {
               new Claim("CustomerConnectionString", user.CustomerConnectionString)
               });
           }
           return principal;
       }
   }
   ```
5. Register the custom factory you just created in your application startup class, after adding Identity service:

   ```
   // Add framework services.
   services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

   services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
           .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
           .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

     services.AddScoped<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, AppClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
   ```
6. Then you could access the claims like :

   ```
   var connectString = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "CustomerConnectionString").Value;
   ```
7. Modify the creating/editing user view/controller , add the customer dropdownlist on view , get the custom id in `Register` function in `AccountController` , query the connectingString of custom from db , and save in `ApplicationUser` object :

   ```
    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
   ```